# Set cargo linker for cross compilation only if necessary

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

According to various guides on cross-compiling Rust I need to set something like this in `.cargo/config`:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
```

In my case I am cross compiling for Linux on Mac. This is fine, but I'd also like to be able to build the code natively on Linux (i.e. not cross-compiling). In that case surely the target is still `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`, but I don't want to override `linker` then.

I guess you can probably do this using a custom `build.rs`, but is there any way to do this from `.cargo/config`? I thought you'd be able to do something like this:

```
[target.'cfg(all(host_os = "macos", target_os = "linux"))']
linker = "x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
```

But there is no `host_os`.

Comment: I am not sure cargo has some feature like this, imho it would be nice to have, if there is not, you may want to check [environment variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#environment-variables) to configure cargo according to build environment

Comment: The target for most Linux systems should be `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`. For Mac I though it's `x86_64-apple-darwin`

Comment: Binaries dynamically linked against glibc often have annoying compatibility issues. I'm trying to use Musl because it's easier to statically link against and generate a properly portable binary. Well, it is with just C code anyway. Might be very difficult with Cargo and C dependencies!

Comment: Ah sweet, it turns out I didn't need to do anything extra to make it statically link Musl. `ldd` reports `Not a dynamic executable`! Anyway this is off topic. I went with the environment variable solution to this problem - thanks @ÖmerErden.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you've put `.cargo/config` inside of your Cargo workspace?

If this the case, you should consider moving host-specific configuration options (such as `target.{target}.linker`) into your user-specific `~/.cargo/config` instead. That way, the linker is not tied to the workspace configuration, but instead to the user: different users on different hosts could have different linkers configured for different targets.

Comment: But then every user that downloads the code will have to manually set up `~/.cargo/config`. Not very useful.

Comment: @Timmmm you assume that everyone will have the cross-compiler named `x86_64-linux-musl-gcc`, which is also not very useful.

Comment: @Timmmm Yes, that's the point: if different users have different environments (like different ways of building a target), they should be set up separately from the committed repository files. On the flip side, putting this in the `~/.cargo/config` file means that it applies for *all* cargo builds for that target, not just your project.

Comment: @Shepmaster True, but given how difficult it is to set up a cross-compiler, and the fact that this is a closed source app I am very happy to prescribe how users (developers) install a cross-compiler (we're using the ones at https://musl.cc/). I feel like "download this, unzip it and put it in your PATH" is a much easier instruction than "figure out how to get a cross-compiler for your platform and then edit `.cargo/config` adding the name of the linker your cross-compiler uses".